# Postfix relay emails with authenticated FROM address quickly and delay unauthenticated ones

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I have setup a mailing server using iRedMail, and a web server with LAMP stack and postfix to relay emails via the mailing server + WP installation. Everything is setup correctly and working just fine. The only thing that bothers me is when I send an email from the web server (WordPress) using an authenticated `FROM` address "no-reply@domain.com" it is triggered in less than a second. However, when I trigger an email with `FROM` address set to anything else "xxxx@domain.com" it keeps spinning for a while (around 5 seconds) and will eventually land in the mailbox.

This is confusing because the logical way is, if there is something wrong with the the other `FROM` address is to not send the email, but the email is being sent, just not passed to the mailing server quickly compared to the first one ( Delay is coming from the web server, when it reaches the mailing server it's dispatched quickly ).

So is there something I'm missing here? or is there a different way to setup postfix to accept any `FROM` address and handle all of them in the same way?

My web server postfix config file "/etc/postfix/main.cf":

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = www.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, www.domain.com, localhost.com, localhost
relayhost = mail.domain.com:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
# outbound relay configurations
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = may
header_size_limit = 4096000
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_by_sender
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
```

"/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd" file

```
mail.domain.com:587  no-reply@domain.com:123456pass
```

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Logs are fine and exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: Does postfix require only a single user password to be able to sent using any `FROM` address? or is there a different setup for something like that?

Comment: I'm looking for an explanation more than a solution. I want to understand how Postfix relay email with different `from` addresses with only a single authenticated address.

Comment: If your `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps` conf treats mail differently based on sender, that would be obvious from the specified file (and also from the mail logs, which would then *not* be equal, and the trace headers of the mail, which would clarify the relays used).

Comment: Thanks @anx I'll dig a little more into this